# Capturing repeated string in one group

Tags: regex, string

I have the following string: "....+2+3+4+6+7...."
I want to capture a group "a plus followed by a digit".
If I write `\^[\d]`, then I will get 5 groups.
I want it as one.

Comment: Just match all matches with `\+\d+`. What is the regex engine?

Comment: This could work : ```(?:\+[\d])+```. Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/tuf6iZ/1)

Comment: `[\+\d]+` should match whole addition.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, `[\+\d]+` matches `++1`. I don't want that. Only exact repetition `+1+2+3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below pattern will capture 1 - n instances of "a plus followed by a digit" as per your original question.

Also fine as per your latest comment, i.e. given `++1` it will match `+1` - "a plus followed by a digit" as requested.

```
(\+\d)+
```

Given the string `++1+2+3`, the above pattern will match `+1+2+3`.

If you do not want to match digits preceded by `++` specifically, the below pattern uses a lookbehind to discount "a plus followed by another plus followed by a digit".

```
(?<!\+)(\+\d)+
```

Given the string `++1+2+3`, the above pattern will match `+2+3`.